# Appwrite Authentication Issues

Tags: authentication, oauth, appwrite

I am using Appwrite to build a client side website (an e-commerce online store). There is a database made in appwrite which has the admin users as well as the customers collections. Now whenever I load the page without being logged in I get the following error: `AppwriteException: User (role: guests) missing scope (account)`

In the products and categories collection, I have ensured that `Any` have the role to **read** the documents only. Whereas I have added an admin teams in the **Auth** tab (where all the admins are the members).

I want to make sure that guests to the client website, are able to only **read** the documents.
Btw I am using reactjs and appwrite
Below is the appwrite backend code, I have written:

```
const getCurrentUser = async () => {
  try {
    const currentUser = await account.get();
    if (currentUser) {
      return currentUser;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
};

const registerUser = async (userData) => {
  try {
    const user = await account.create(
      ID.unique(),
      userData.email,
      userData.password,
      userData.name
    );
    if (user) {
      await loginUser({ email: userData.email, password: userData.password });
    } else {
      return undefined;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

const loginUser = async (loginDetails) => {
  try {
    return await account.createEmailSession(
      loginDetails.email,
      loginDetails.password
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

const deleteCurrentSession = async () => {
  try {
    const {$id} = await getCurrentUser();
    // return await account.deleteSession("current");
    return await account.deleteSession($id);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

The getCurrentUser() runs everytime the app is refreshed, so in the console I am getting the above given error
Note: Also I am not able to logout, the session isn't getting deleted.

Answer (score 0):

It's expected for your console to show an error because `await account.get()` throws an exception if the user is not logged in and you have a catch block that logs the error.